# how to get count the events of each topic's child from another table?

Tags: mysql

i have 2 table's.

> table TOPICS
>      topic_id | auto increment
>      topic_pid | int  => points to his parent
>      topic_name | string
>
> table events
>      topic_id | int => points to topic table
>      title | string

i want to get results that show me each How many events each topic and its children have?

for example

```
TOPIC‌ TABLE 

————————————-

topic_id | topic_pid | topic_name

  1           0         product

  2           1         downloadable

  3           2         movie
```

```
 EVENT TABLE

 ————————————-

 topic_id | title 

   3         buy

   3         like

   2         like
```

my ideal answer:

```
  name      | event count
  product        3
  downloadable   3
  movie          2
```

because movie is downloadable's child and downloadable is product's child

my topic child have child

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Comment: mysql -v is 5.7.27